# iOS free trial - then discounted price - then regular price - is it possible

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I would like to offer a paid subscription to an iOS app with the following pricing plan:

1st month - free trial.
Next 3 months - at 20% off.
Afterwards - full price.

Is this possible? Maybe using a combination of an introductory offer and offer codes?